# JavaFX hover transitions for all Buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I wan't to change the color of any button in my application from red to blue fluent when the mouse is over it.

This is my css code so far:

```
.button{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(225,0,0);
}

.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
    transition: -fx-background-color 2s;
}
```

Now I'm looking for something like this:

```
.button:hover{
    transition: -fx-background-color 2s;
}
```